# Laravel 5 and ODBC

Tags: laravel, pdo, laravel-5, odbc, 4d-database

Can `Laravel 5` connect via `PDO to ODBC`? We have a old `4th Dimension` database that needs to be integrated temporarily ( 2 years ) . But Im not sure if it will be able to communicate with Eloquent ORM.

Answer (score 0):

There you have a [odbc driver for laravel 4](https://github.com/ccovey/odbc-driver), I cannot ensure that it works on laravel 5, laravel 4 **natively doesn't support odbc connections** and I guess after some research that laravel 5 doesn´t support it too.

If the driver for laravel 4 works on laravel 5 please give a feedback.

Comment: I have tested it, composer will not install it with laravel 5+